# Folder size limit reached?

Tags: python, filesystem

I have a Python script that copies files from a very large folder (109.05 GB, and that contains spread into subfolders, 13.071 items) from an external HD to another one.

The script I used has raised none exception. Unfortunately, when I look at the destination folder it only has (6.563 items, totalling 58,8 GB) it is supposed to have the same size and contains as many files as the source one...

Every file I search for seems to have been transferred tough.

My question is: Is it a display bug? Or is there really a folder size limit and some file might have been implicitly overwritten?

For those of you who know a bit of Python as it is an easy script I join it here:

```
source_dir = r'/media/julien/Elements/Ma Musique'
dest_dir = r'/media/julien/TOSHIBA EXT/All my music'

def copy_all_files(source_dir,destination_dir):
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for file in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print (path.encode("utf-8"))
            shutil.copy2(path, destination_dir) 


copy_all_files(source_dir,dest_dir)
print("DONE")
```

Comment: As great as python is, what could be simpler than `cd /media/julien && rsync -a 'Elements/Ma Musique' 'TOSHIBA EXT/All my music'` ?

Comment: Sure @dessert but the thing is that I want to include mode features to this script after so I'll stick to Python for this purpose that will evolve..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one of the files that have duplicate names is copied regardless of which original sub-directory they came from.

**During execution:**

All files are indeed copied, but files in the destination directory with identical name as the source will be overwritten without exception. So only the last copied file will remain in the destination directory.

Please read here:

[shutil — High-level file operations](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/shutil.html)

> If dst is a directory, a file with the same basename as src is created
>   (or overwritten) in the directory specified

**This does not mean all your distinct files are copied. If more than one file have different content and the same name, only one will be copied regardless of file content differences.**

To see what is happening while you execute your code, Please run the modified version below:

```
import os
import shutil
from termcolor import colored

source_dir = r'/media/julien/Elements/Ma Musique'
dest_dir = r'/media/julien/TOSHIBA EXT/All my music'

def copy_all_files(source_dir,destination_dir):
    failed = 0
    succeeded = 0
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for file in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            if os.path.exists(destination_dir + '/' + file):
                print(file + colored(' from ', 'yellow') + root + colored(' filename already exist, cannot copy', 'red'))
                # Normally destination files will be overwritten without exception, but now an error message is printed instead
                failed += 1
            else:
                shutil.copy2(path, destination_dir)
                print(file + colored(' from ', 'yellow') + root + colored(' copied successfully', 'green'))
                succeeded += 1
    print(colored('copied files ', 'green') + str(succeeded))
    print(colored('duplicate not copied files ', 'red') + str(failed))



copy_all_files(source_dir,dest_dir)
print("DONE")
```

**To answer your question:**

> My question is: Is it a display bug ? Or is there really a folder size
>   limit and some file might have been implicitly overwritten?

It appears that you have different files with the same filename under different sub-directories in the source disk for example:

File 1 `/media/julien/Elements/Ma Musique/audio/book1.mp3`

File 2 `/media/julien/Elements/Ma Musique/audio_books/book1.mp3`

When they are copied to the destination disk, they all go to the same directory (sub-directory structure is **NOT** preserved in your code) so the following happens:

**First:** file 1 is copied so the destination directory will look like this:

```
`/media/julien/TOSHIBA EXT/All my music/book1.mp3`
```

**Then:** file 2 is copied so `shutil.copy2()` overwrites **file 1** in the destination directory which has the filename `book1.mp3` with **file 2** which has the same filename and you end up with the destination directory looking like this:

```
`/media/julien/TOSHIBA EXT/All my music/book1.mp3`
```

I hope It is clear now.